# Flink and Kafka configuration for retries

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have done a Flink configuration for retries which is working

```
env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.failureRateRestart(
   3, // number of restart attempts
   Time.of(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
   Time.of(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // delay
));
```

But I'm using another configuration based on FlinkKafkaConsumer to receive messages and I don't know of to configure for retries.

For example Spring has its own ErrorHandler, I expected something similar for FlinkKafkaConsumer and FlinkKafkaProducer.

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
    new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template), 3));
```

Are both campatibles, **RestartStrategy** and **FlinkKafkaConsumer**? If FlinkKafkaConsumer can be configured for retries can I use only one or should I configure the RestartStrategy?

Comment: What do You mean by another configuration based on FlinkKafkaConsumer , can You provide an example ?

Comment: For example Spring has its own ErrorHandler (I added to the post), I expected something similar for FlinkKafkaConsumer and FlinkKafkaProducer.